# Confused about Google maps API Android version

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I've activated Google MAPs API v3 in the Google API console. but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) references v2. Is it the case that the documentation hasn't been updated, or am I missing something? Apologies but I'm new to the Maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You activated the wrong service. To use Google Maps V2 in Android you should activate **Google Maps Android API v2** service.

Comment: I've actually activated "Google Maps API v2" and "Google Maps API v3", but that doesn't explain why the documentation only references to v2. I'm assuming you can use v3 with Android?

Comment: As stated in the answer, you should activate "Google Maps Android API v2", not "Google Maps API v2", and not "Google Maps API v3". Here's the official docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2